# Is it permissible for a married women to have friendship with a married man?

Tags: halal-haram, relationships

I am a married woman and I have a male friend who is just like a brother to me. My husband knows and has no issue. We have never met, we just talk on facebook. we have planned a meeting along with our spouses to strengthen this friendship. His wife is a good friend of mine too and has no issue.

Is it allowed for us to carry on with this friendship? We feel like we are more like a brother and a sister to each other. Will Allah be pleased with me?

Answer (score 0):

In islam there is no concept of Male Friend, You may be married or unmarried and why you want to make a friendship with a boy to whom you never met before. Are you'r faith (more) powerfull then (companions of prophet muhammed sallallahu-alihi-wasallam)sahaba, tabaen, they also have to follow the islamic rules and have to do wear hijaab and cover there body and not permitted to talk with namuharram. Even you have to maintain hijaab in front of you'r cousine. So I request you to break this friendship.

Answer (score 0):

Having relationships with Men outside the marriage is clearly denied in Islam as i know, now if you are working and you confront with Men in the subject of work then that's fine with keeping Al-Hayya and avoiding any kind of pampering, now for your question i noticed that you says : "I have a male friend who is just like a brother", a brother ? all Muslims are brothers !! what do you mean by brother ? what are the subjects that you talk about ? you have a husband to chat with, isn't enough ?, i guess if you respond honestly to these questions you would be more clear about your position, but if you want some advice from me, then quit doing these kinda things because you will feel more comfortable chating with your husband especially in some taboo/pleased like subjects than a stranger man, it is obvious, if you have a communication problem with your husband that lead you to do this, then try to solve the problem with love and respect to your husband.

+1 if it helped, thank you.

Comment: As your answer relates to having relationships with Men when married. The OP is not about relationship it is about friendship which is different.

Comment: @anas Please read just the first line of my response and you'll recognize that am talking about friendship not marriage !! ... thank you ...

Comment: `Having relationships with Men outside the marriage is clearly denied in Islam` , there is a difference between relationship and friendship. This is what i pointed out.